# HTML textarea cuts off beginning new lines

Tags: html, textarea, newline

An HTML text area works fine with new lines ("\n") when they're **after** any other content in the text area, whether it be whitespace characters like spaces or tabs ("\t") or not.

However, when text area content **begins** with a new line (for example, "\ntest"), that new line gets cut off on display.

Any ideas on what causes this/how to remedy it?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#element-restrictions - *A single newline may be placed immediately after the start tag of pre and textarea elements. If the element's contents are intended to start with a newline, two consecutive newlines thus need to be included by the author.*

Comment: @AleksandrM - so, this isn't a Struts 2 issue at all then...has this already been answered in another question?

Comment: Yes, not a S2 issue. *has this already been answered in another question?* - Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @AleksandrM I've updated my question so that it points to the correct control.  If you post your comment as an answer I will upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be by the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#element-restrictions).

> A single newline may be placed immediately after the start tag of `pre` and `textarea` elements. If the element's contents are intended to start with a newline, two consecutive newlines thus need to be included by the author.

Note that in the past there were some bugs in the various browsers regarding leading new lines in elements:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591988
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62901